# Компиляция файла

Tags: delphi, pascal, компилятор

На компьютере установлен компилятор pascal. Есть .pas файл (написанный на pascal), название которого находится в string переменной s1 .
Хочу написать программу на delphi, которая сама скомпилирует этот файл.

Comment: Возможно, следует изучить возможности работы с компилятором pascal из командной строки. Запустить компилятор из командной строки и в качестве параметра передать файл.

Answer (score 1):

Тебе нужна функция на запуск программы и ожидание.
Вот тут смотри [Execute a program and wait until it is done](http://delphidabbler.com/tips/17)
Т.е. ты запускаешь компилятор (типа c:\appl\compile.exe), а в качестве параметра передаешь c:\docs\1.pas. На выходе должен получить 1.exe